# How to suppress welcome message when embedding SWI-Prolog in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, swi-prolog

I am writing a C++ program with SWI-Prolog embedded. Every time it is executed, the SWI-Prolog will print the welcome message on terminal. I tried suppressing it like

```
#include<SWI-cpp.h>

PlEngine *ple;
void startSWIProlog(char *argv0)
{
  char *av[10];
  int ac = 0;
  av[ac++] = argv0;
  av[ac++] = "--quiet";
  av[ac++] = "-g";
  av[ac++] = "true";
  av[ac] = NULL;

  if (!ple) ple = new PlEngine(ac, av);
}
```

but it doesn't work. It seems the PlEngine ignores the passed options. So any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Have you read [Section 2.4.4 from the Manual?](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,+%272.4%27,+swi%28%27/doc/Manual/cmdline.html%27%29%29) Try the example and see if it works - you seem to have the general idea already with `-g true`, but the manual seems to imply _either_ `-q` or `-g true` is sufficient.

Comment: I tried `-q`, `-g true` separately or combined, neither works. When I am using it to start the swipl in the shell as `$swipl -g true`, it works and the message is suppressed, but if I am using the `-g true` option in the embedding program (C++ in my case), it doesn't work. The welcome message is still printed.

Comment: So `-t` and `halt` don't work? Hmmm.

Comment: Finally find the reason. It only happens in my CentOS 6 with SWI-Prolog 5.7.11 installed from the repository. In my Ubuntu 14.04 with SWI-Prolog 6.6.4 installed, passing either "--quiet" or "-q" works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It does seems it ignores argv. I've tried all I could to no solution (-g true, --quiet, -q, NULL here and there, nothing works). The solution lies in another place.

Now, you should simply initializes normally as:

```
if (!PL_initialise(argc, argv))
    PL_halt(EXIT_FAILURE); /* if you wish to exit in case of fail */
```

But when compiling (*) give the command:

```
swipl-ld prog.c prog.pl -o prog.x -pl-options,-q
```

And you should have it silenced.

(*) Note: this is actually a test for C language. I did not try C++. But I think its worth to answer here.